# Embed Video to website from google drive want to add button for playbackspeed

Tags: html, html5-video

Here I have uploaded a  video to google drive and i want to embbed it to my website I want to add buttons to change the playback speed.
here is code so far

```html
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/14PDQfE1wvt4jrAj-CeW1tFV-W3pCtS7D/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```

I need help with mp4 files to add buttons for changing playback speed like 1.0x 1.25x 1.50x etc.
https://prnt.sc/1rl9hil
I have figure out for mp3 files which is below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>
<style>
body {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
}

#actions {
  background: white;
}

#actions button {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #555555;
  border-radius: 12px;
   
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>


  <button onclick="getPlaySpeed()" type="button">What is the playback speed?</button>
    
  <audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1bDkkNlMt2TIrwBLtgjFoL5odO7rbGS06">
</audio>


  <p>Audiobook Speed</p>
  <div id="actions">
  <button onclick="setPlaySpeed(1.00)" type="button">1.00x</button><button onclick="setPlaySpeed(1.25)" type="button">1.25x</button><button onclick="setPlaySpeed(1.50)" type="button">1.50x</button><button onclick="setPlaySpeed(1.75)" type="button">1.75x</button><button onclick="setPlaySpeed(2.0)" type="button">2.0x</button>
    
  </div>

<script>

var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.playbackRate = 1.75;


function setPlaySpeed(speed) {
  audio.playbackRate = speed;
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

you can embed a video using the video tag

```
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source src="[video file.mp4]" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

and to change the playback speed it is basically the same thing as for the audio

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("video");
audio.playbackRate = 1.75;
```

Comment: i tryed <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/14PDQfE1wvt4jrAj-CeW1tFV-W3pCtS7D/preview"></iframe>       but i cannot click on play button at all its like its not there.  if its small video file it works. less than 40 mb

Comment: why not divide your video into smaller parts?